# What should be documented in the syntax-section of a documentation topic?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Looking at the [java streams documentation topic's syntax section](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/88/streams#t=201607220938220200745&a=syntax), this currently contains the line

> Stream.generate(() -> value)

Although this lambda is a possible value for the parameter, it is certainly not the only way to invoke this method. Should this section just contain one example of how to invoke each method? Should examples for other kinds of suppliers be added?

Is the lambda-style preferable for all methods taking parameters of functional interface types?