# What should be placed into 'Syntax' and 'Parameters' tabs?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics, parameters-section, syntax-section

I have checked other question that looks similar ([Guidance for using Syntax and Parameters in documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329132/guidance-for-using-syntax-and-parameters-in-documentation), [How to add Syntax and/or Parameters to an already created topic in Documentation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328963/how-to-add-syntax-and-or-parameters-to-an-already-created-topic-in-documentation), [What should be documented in the syntax-section of a documentation topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328912/what-should-be-documented-in-the-syntax-section-of-a-documentation-topic)) but nothing really helped me.

So my question implies those topics in documentation, that is rather broad and covers many examples and many different functions. For example PHP's [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/204/arrays), [file handling](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/1426/file-handling). Both contains numerous examples and numerous functions with different syntax and parameters.

First. Is it a good practice to put all functions and then all their parameters into "Syntax" and "Parameters" respectively? I'm pretty sure, that it will turn those sections into mess.

Second. Some contributors after adding an example for a single function, also add this function into "Syntax" and its parameters into "Parameters". But I thinks this bad too, because we have, let's say, a dozen functions in the topic, so why only one is in "Syntax"?

So what is the best for this situation? I think that in current implementation both those tabs are badly adapted for broad topics.

Comment: There's a hidden question here: "Do we need this section at all, given very few docs here (to date) are specific to a class?"

Comment: Those, who tagged it "duplicate", did you read the question? I mentioned that question and it does not help at all and it does not have an answer.